# Should `linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include` be sufficient to compile against the Linux headers?

Tags: c, linux

Say I have `main.c`:

```
#include <linux/list.h>

int main() {}
```

`uname -r` resolves to the `5.13.0-28-generic` and I run `Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64`.

See what happens:

```
username@username-laptop:~$ gcc -o main -I/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include main.c 
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic/include/linux/kernel.h:8,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic/include/linux/list.h:9,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic/include/linux/linkage.h:8:10: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include <asm/linkage.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

OK. Seems `asm/linkage.h` is platform-specific so I can't get if from the `-generic` headers. `sudo find / -name linkage.h | grep x86` suggests the `/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-28/arch/x86/include` include. So let's add that one too:

```
username@username-laptop:~$ gcc -o main -I/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include -I/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-28/arch/x86/include main.c 
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic/include/linux/kernel.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic/include/linux/list.h:9,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic/include/linux/compiler.h:250:10: fatal error: asm/rwonce.h: No such file or directory
  250 | #include <asm/rwonce.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Have no idea what is wrong with my configuration. Any ideas?

Comment: For userspace code, you can only use the linux and asm headers that are included with the C library headers.

Comment: `int main() {}` But are you writing user-space code or kernel code? `linux/list.h` is for kernel code. Kernel has no `main`.

Comment: User space. Probably, my mistake.

Comment: But what the right way to get the executable out of gcc then?

Comment: Well you cannot use `#include <linux/list.h>` because it does not exist in a usable form. If you really need it, you could use [this one](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/~kazutomo/list/list.h) that has been modified from the kernel source and can be included as `#include "list.h"`. It uses GCC extensions such as `typeof` and is GPL licensed. Other linked list implementations are available.